# Quitar Cursor de TextBox C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Cuando un textBox toma el foco Aparece una barra titilante ...
Como puedo hacer para q no aparesca ? 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44174/5622844) te puede ayudar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bueno, lo he logrado de alguna forma con el código que te he puesto en en [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62736/quitar-cursor-de-textbox-c#comment113772_62736).

En la clase `Form` que implementa esos controles `TextBox`, haces lo siguiente:

1. Haces `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` al principio del archivo `MiForm.cs` *(Donde `MiForm` es el nombre del archivo de codigo correspondiente al `Form` que utilizas.)*
2. Defines el método externo `HideCaret`:

   ```
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
   ```

Luego para cada `TextBox` configuras el evento `GotFocus` de la manera siguiente:

```
foreach (TextBox item in MiColeccionDeTextBoxes) {
    item.GotFocus += delegate { HideCaret(item.Handle); }
}
```

Y con eso tienes lo que necesitas para completar el `Form`, debajo dejo todo el codigo de un `Form1.cs` que hice mientras lo intentaba:

```
// Recuerda el using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextBox[] texts = { txt1, txt2 };
        foreach (TextBox item in texts)
            item.GotFocus += delegate { HideCaret(item.Handle);  };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null)) {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.txt1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.txt2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // txt1
        // 
        this.txt1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 48);
        this.txt1.MaxLength = 1;
        this.txt1.Name = "txt1";
        this.txt1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.txt1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // txt2
        // 
        this.txt2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 74);
        this.txt2.MaxLength = 1;
        this.txt2.Name = "txt2";
        this.txt2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.txt2.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
        this.Controls.Add(this.txt2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.txt1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Test Focus";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt2;
}
```

Comment: Voy A probarlo y te comento...Muchas Gracias ...

Comment: NaCl Gracias ....Buenisimoo

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido :)

Answer (score 3):

Aconsejaria que no utilices TextBox para representar cada cuadrado, podrias usar un picturebox y el numero lo dibujas

[How to draw text on picturebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849359/how-to-draw-text-on-picturebox)

[Drawing Graphics in C Sharp](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Drawing_Graphics_in_C_Sharp)

de esta forma tendras los eventos pero controlas las acciones, no sera tan directo como asignar el .Text, pero no tendras cursor alguno sobre el control

Para hacer mas simple la asignacion del numero sino quieres usar el evento Paint, podrias ver si con

```
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
```

o quizas algo como ser

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
{
    using (SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
    {
        using (Font myFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 24))
        {
            g.DrawString("aqui numero", myFont, myBrush, 10, 10);
            pictureBox1.Image = bm;
        }
    }
}
```

cuando quieres mostrar un numero lo dibujas en una imagen y lo asignas al picturebox, si necesitas asignar un color de fondo siempre podras hacerlo sin problemas