# Seleccionar el contenido de un TextBox al tomar el foco

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Hay alguna forma de que cuando el foco se posiciona sobre cada control de tipo `TextBox` contenido en un form, se seleccione el texto contenido en estos?

Me refiero a si hay alguna forma de hacer esto sin tener que programar el evento ENTER por cada cuadro de texto, ya que tengo muchos.

Se me ocurre que con un `foreach` pero no veo en que evento insertar el código.

EDITO:

Entre la solución que me brindó el amigo NaCI y algunos retoques que le hice yo para que funcione tal como esperaba, el código me quedó así:

```
private void RecorrerControles(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            if (c.HasChildren) this.RecorrerControles(c);
            {
                foreach (TextBox t in c.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                {
                    t.Enter += delegate
                    {
                        t.SelectAll();
                        t.HideSelection = false;
                    };
                    t.Leave += delegate
                    {
                        t.SelectionLength = 0;
                    };
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Yo lo definí como un método privado para accederlo sólo desde este form, al cual llamo desde el constructor del form.

En primera instancia no me funcionaba porque tengo el form organizado en paneles y la solución que me pasó NaCI sólo recorría los TextBox contenidos directamente en el form y no en los paneles. Para ello, definí una función que se llama a sí misma si el control tiene "hijos" y recorre los controles contenidos, hasta que no haya más "hijos".

Comment: En el evento `GotFocus`: `foreach (TextBox t in TextBoxes) t.GotFocus = delegate { t.Select(0, t.Text.Length); };` [Relacionado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63493/4499)

Comment: Con el evento GotFocus te referís al evento ENTER? Porque no encuentro ningún evento GotFocus. O en qué control debería buscar ese evento? Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pueden ver el historial de ediciones para mi respuesta anterior.

Esta solución funciona perfectamente como esperas:

```
// Recuerda el using System.Linq;
// y el using System.Windows.Forms;
// Form1 es tu formulario
public Form1() 
{
    foreach (TextBox t in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) 
    {
        t.Enter += delegate { 
            t.SelectAll(); 
            t.HideSelection = false; 
        };
        t.Leave += delegate { 
            t.SelectionLength = 0; 
            t.HideSelection = true; 
        };
    } 
}
```

La propiedad `HideSelection` se encarga de ocultar la selección del control al tomar el foco, el código si tienes seleccionado el texto, pero no se refleja en el formulario, pero aun así puedes realizar acciones con la selección.

Comment: Probé con esta última, pero no me funciona. El editor no me encontró ningún error, salvo que la lista de textboxes hay que declararla como IEnumerable en lugar de IList porque sino da error de conversión implícita.

Comment: No, no seleccionada nada :S

Comment: Tampoco :S Por las dudas probé con t.TextLength en lugar de t.Text.Length.. pero sigue sin seleccionar nada

Comment: Cuando se carga el form todos los textbox están vacíos, lo que hago es cargar un texto en el primero (caracteres o numeros) o en cualquiera de ellos, saco el foco y lo vuelvo a poner para probar, pero no me selecciona el texto.

Comment: El control es un textbox común, de los que vienen con el editor de Windows Forms.

Comment: @Willy616 Ya lo he probado, esa versión debe de funcionar.

Comment: @NaCI perdon por la tardanza en mi respuesta.. probe asi como me indicas pero sigue sin funcionar.. a lo mejor tendra que ver que tengo organizado el form en paneles? Es decir, tengo un SplitContainer, en el panel 1 una serie de botones y en el panel 2 una serie de paneles, todos acoplados al panel 2 del split.. los txt estan dentro de cada uno de estos "subpaneles" dentro del panel 2 del split..

Por esta razon, tambien probe el foreach de esta forma:

foreach (TextBox t in this.splPrincipal.Panel2.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
...

Pero de ninguna de las dos formas me funciona..

Comment: Así como lo he probado me funciona perfectamente, has pensado en hacerle debug? A ver si el `foreach` realiza los ajustes necesarios? Probablemente tendrás que agregarlos manualmente en el código para luego hacer foreach a la colección.

Comment: Finalmente me funcionó! Pero agrego dos salvedades:
1) Como bien me indicaste, tuve que agregar control por control a una lista y luego recorrer la lista (no se por qué con el "this.controls.OfType<TextBox>()" no funciona..
2) Dentro del evento Leave no hace falta el HideSelection, con poner el length de la selección en 0 es suficiente, de hecho, hay que borrar esta línea, porque en mi caso el foco se quedaba trabado en un único TextBox y no podía avanzar a los siguientes..
Teniendo en cuenta estas dos cosas, funciona perfecto.. muchas gracias @NaCI

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido, haré las mejoras en cuanto tome un pc :P

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu código, me dispuse a probar otra funcionalidad, el problema que detecte es que si envío un contenedor simple con textbox no funciona, pero el contenedor esta dentro de otro contenedor funciona perfectamente, en este caso el código inicializa todos los textbox que se encuentran dentro de un contenedor, ya sea un form, un groupbox (dentro de un groupbox)

```
private void InitTextBox(Control control)
        {
            foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
            {
                if (c.HasChildren) InitTextBox(c);
                {
                    foreach (TextBox t in c.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                        t.Text = "";
                }
}
```

seguiré probando, mi idea es extenderlo para por ejemplo poner en readonly (false o true) de todos los textbox y cosas similares